# Custom header on OPTIONS in fine uploader s3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I am using react FineUploaderS3, with params:

```
this.myUploader = new FineUploaderS3({
  options: {
    request: {
      endpoint: "endpoint",
      accessKey: "accessKey",
      params: {
       Authorization: 'authorization'
      }
    },
    chunking: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    resume: {
      enabled: true
    },
    signature: {
      endpoint: "signatureUrl",
    },
    iframeSupport: {
      localBlankPagePath: null
    },
    params: {
      Authorization: 'authorization'
    }
  }
});
```

When I checked OPTION request, there is no Authorization param. How to add it? It seems fine uploader currently no support that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not such option in FineUploaderS3. It shouldn't be, according to [w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#preflight-request) OPTION should not contain user credentials, authorization param.